# ASP.NET MVC edit operation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditArticle", new { ArticleID = article.ArticleID })
```

I retrieved Article by ArticleID and return to edit page like this:

```
public ActionResult EditArticle(Guid ArticleID)
{
    AddArticleModel AddArticleModel = new AddArticleModel();
    AddArticleModel.Categories = entity.TBL_CATEGORIES.Select(a => a);
    AddArticleModel.Article = dbo.SelectArticleById(ArticleID);

    return View(AddArticleModel);
}
```

There is no problem until here.

And in my editing page I'm changing some attributes of article (not all attributes).For example I'm changing title, content, and updateddate. Like this:

```
@model DunyaYazilim.Models.AddArticleModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditArticle";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutAuthor.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm((string)ViewBag.FormAction, "Author"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Makale gönderilirken bir hata oluştu. Lütfen daha sonra tekrar deneyin.")

    <div>
        <div class="label_header">@Html.Label("Kategori Seçiniz:")</div>
        <div>@Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", new SelectList(Model.Categories, "CategoryID", "Name"),Model.Article.TBL_CATEGORIES.Name)</div>
        <div class="label_header">@Html.Label("Makale Başlık:")</div>
        <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Article.Title, new { @class = "my_textbox" })</div>
        <div class="label_header">@Html.Label("Makale Açıklama:")</div>
        <div>@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Article.Description, new { @class = "my_textarea" })</div>
        <div class="label_header">@Html.Label("Makale İçerik:")</div>
        <div>@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Article.ArticleContent, new { @class = "my_textarea" })</div>
        <div><input type="submit" value="Gönder" class="my_button" /></div>
    </div>
}
```

And then I post it to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditArticle(AddArticleModel AddArticleModel, String CategoryID)
{
    //TODO: update database...
    return View(AddArticleModel);
}
```

But unchanged attributes are return null(ArticleID, UserID, etc).So I cant Update the database, Because I dont have ArticleID after posting. What is the reason for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Since we have no code of your html/cshtml it would be hard to determine what values are returning to your `EditArticle` method.

Comment: I updated the post.And added the editing page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC doesn't maintain anything for you between requests.  When you post to your action, it will post only the values that you have set up in your form.  As you don't have your article id or user id in the form (or anywhere else, e.g. route or query string), MVC won't know about them during model binding for your EditArticle action.

If you want the extra details to be sent through with your post, you can put hidden fields in the form, e.g.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Article.Id)
```

Comment: When I do this and debug the project, EditArticle(AddArticleModel AddArticleModel, String CategoryID) method is not firing.

Comment: Also I use this too : @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Article.IsActive) "IsActive" is boolean. May cause this error?

Comment: Was it firing before you added the HiddenFor?  What does the generated HTML look like?  Regarding IsActive, I wouldn't bother with it unless it is actually editable.  Just post back the ID, to recall which entity is being edited, and the data that is actually being edited.  Then pull the entity out of storage, update the required fields, and save it back.

Comment: Null attributes allready not neccesary. We need only ID. Thanks a lot.